# How KDE website changed drupal path

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

When you go to http://akademy.kde.org/

the register link is http://akademy.kde.org/register - no **user** in path

It goes to http://akademy.kde.org/user/register **with user**

This is a drupal website. How you think they did this? and how to make it stay at this path http://akademy.kde.org/register **no user in path**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://akademy.kde.org/register`

simply redirect to

`http://akademy.kde.org/user/register`

...i guess they just make a shorthand path alias, go to `http://yoursite.com/admin/build/path` and you can make your owns (maybe you'll need to enable the path module, is boundled with drupal)

If you truly need a redirect, check out the path_redirect module as aularon suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Drupal's [`path_redirect`](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect).

The index page for http://akademy.kde.org/register probably contains a simple redirect.

Also in PHP it is this easy `header("Location: http://akademy.kde.org/user/register")`

Answer (score 1):

Check [drupal's `path_redirect` module](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect).

Answer (score 0):

cookies/.htaccess/modified templates?
what is the normal http://drupal.foo/register/? url?